# how to split csv file content based on 'dot' in python code

Tags: python-2.7, csv

how to split csv file content based on dot in python code

eg:  Smt. Pattu Ramamurthy => [Smt] [Pattu Ramamurthy]

please anyone tell

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is

```
 import csv

 with open(csvfile,'rb') as f:

     fcsv=csv.reader(f,delimiter='.')

     for row in fcsv:
         print row
```

I would recommend reading the documentation of [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: thanks for replaying ,but actually that code code not giving exact answer     ['']
['']
['Title and NAME']
['']
['']
['Shri', ' R', 'Gopalakrishnan']
['']
['']
['']
['']
['']
['Smt', ' Pattu Ramamurthy']
['']
['']
['']
['']
['Shri', ' P', 'Thirugnanam']
['']
['']
['']
['']
['']
['Shri', ' B', 'Ganeshamurthy']
['']
['']
['']
['']
I want like, [Smt] [Pattu Ramamurthy]

Comment: Could you please post an excerpt or an example of a csv file then?